# How to do a PHP regex search and save as variables?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have the following line in my htaccess. I would like to convert it to PHP, but I am not sure how to accomplish this?

`RewriteRule ^sessions/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ sessions.php?session=$1&part=$2&activity=$3&step=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

How can I match this `sessions/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/`, and apply the regex areas as php variables?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/preg_match

Comment: I was playing around with `preg_match`, but I get seem to make it work. I keep getting an unknown modifier error.

Comment: You probably forgot to escape the `/` in your paths, e.g. `/sessions\/([.....`.

Comment: The one in the original question: `sessions/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/` I tried escaping the `/` but that didn't help. i.e. `preg_match($uri, 'sessions/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/', $matches);`

Comment: I just need help converting `sessions/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/` to a valid preg_match regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ?

```
$strUrl = "sessions/abc/def/gh/ijk/";
if(preg_match("/^sessions\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\//", $strUrl , $matched)) {
  print_r($matched);
} else {
    echo "No matches.";
}
```

Then you have $matched[1], $matched[2], $matched[3], $matched[4].